# Included jsp file with google map not showing the map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a jsp page which includes a another jsp file which has a google map. But when I access the parent page the div in which the jsp file is included is getting a CSS property value "overflow: hidden" due to which the map is not shown.

Code for parent jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/style.css"  />
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showHeatMap(){
  $('#heatDiv').toggle(true);
  $('#exportToCSVHeatMap').removeAttr('disabled');
  $('#dummyFenceMap').style.overflow="visible";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
      <div id="heatMapDiv" style="display:none">
  heat map
      <div class="div-inline">
        <div class="div-daily">From Date (MM/DD/YYYY)</div>
        <input type="text" name="fromDateHM" id="datepicker4" class="input-inline" />
      </div>
      <div class="div-inline">
        <div class="div-daily">To Date (MM/DD/YYYY)</div>
        <input type="text" name="toDateHM" id="datepicker5" class="input-inline" />
      </div>

      <div id="buttonDiv">
        <input type="button" value="Show Heat Map" onclick="showHeatMap()" />
        <input type="button" value="Export To CSV" id="exportToCSVHeatMap" onclick="exportToCSVHeatMap()" disabled="disabled"/>
      </div> <!-- buttonDiv -->

      <div id="heatDiv" class="heat-map">
        <div class="div-daily">Heat Map</div>
        <div id="heatMap" style="display= block; width= 800px; height= 800px; "><jsp:include page="../jsp/dummyheatmap.jsp?name=test&id=1001"></jsp:include></div>
      </div> <!-- footTraffic -->
  </div> <!-- heatMapDiv -->

</body>
</html>
```

Included jsp file code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>dummy heat map</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/style.css"  />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #fenceMap { height: 50% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* For Google Map.*/

function googleMapinitialize(){
var fenceAdd=new google.maps.LatLng(37.2146,121.5545);
var mapProp = {
        center:fenceAdd,
        zoom:30,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dummyFenceMap"),mapProp);

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var location = "2001 Gateway PI, San Jose, CA";

if(!geocoder) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

var geocoderRequest = {
    address: location
};

var myCity = null;
var marker = null;
var infowindow = null;
geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest, function(results, status) {
    if (status =="" || status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
        alert("'" + location + "' not found!!!");
    } else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        fenceAdd = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.hb,results[0].geometry.location.ib);
        if (!marker) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                raiseOnDrag:false,
                draggable:true
            });
            marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
                if (!infowindow) {
                  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      disableAutoPan:true,
                      maxWidth:100
                  });
                }
                var content = '<strong>' + results[0].formatted_address + '</strong>';
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);                   
            });

        }
    }
    myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
        center:fenceAdd,
        radius:125,
        strokeColor:"#0000ff",
        strokeOpacity:0.1,
        strokeWeight:0.1,
        fillColor:"#0000ff",
        fillOpacity:0.20,
        map:map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(){
        infowindow.close();
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dblclick', function(){
        window.open("<%=request.getContextPath() %>/jsp/googleMapPopup.jsp?fenceAddress="+$('#haddr').val(),'ADDRESSMAP','height=400,width=600');
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', googleMapinitialize);
</script>
</head>
<body onload="googleMapinitialize()">
<h1>Name : <%=request.getParameter("name")%> & id : <%=request.getParameter("id")%></h1>
<div id="dummyFenceMap" style="height=80%;border:1px solid #ff0000;overflow:visible;">
</div><!-- new-div-tag2 -->
<h1>Map end</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The #heatMap div has a height of 2 / 11px and overflow: hidden. When I edit the overflow property to visible I see the google logo & map type

Can anyone help me what is wrong in my code?

Comment: With the line `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', googleMapinitialize);`, I don't believe that you also need `<body onload="googleMapinitialize()">`

Comment: That's true but that is not the issue. The issue is the div is not showing the map.

Comment: When accessing the included page on its own does the map show? Are there any console errors? Using the net panel in Firebug or equivalent can you check whether the map tiles and files are being pulled through from Google?

Comment: On accessing the included page on its own the map is shown. In the Chrome developer tools I did not see any errors. Also when I expand the div I see many div's which are created with class like gmnoprint, gmnoscreen etc. One of div's also has a link says "Click to see this area on google maps"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding following style to the included JSP file's 'dummyFenceMap' div.

```
style="border:1px solid #ff0000;position:relative; left:150px; top:10px; width:500px; height:400px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px"
```

After adding the above style the Map is shown in the embedded JSP file.

But facing a new issue that is - the Google map is shown in 3/4th part of the div rest is blank. But when I resize the browser window the Google Map is redrawn properly. How to resolve this issue?